# Copy contents of one textbox to another

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose an entry is made in a textbox. Is it possible to retain the same entered text in a second text box? If so, how is this done?

```
<html>
      <label>First</label>
      <input type="text" name="n1" id="n1">
      <label>Second</label>
      <input type="text" name="n1" id="n1"/>
</html>
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
<script>
function sync()
{
  var n1 = document.getElementById('n1');
  var n2 = document.getElementById('n2');
  n2.value = n1.value;
}
</script>
<input type="text" name="n1" id="n1" onkeyup="sync()">
<input type="text" name="n2" id="n2"/>
```

Comment: simple, simultaneous, perfect!

Comment: You can generalize this function by adding two parameters: the `input_field` (which would typically be passed in as `this`) and the string representing the id of the element you want to copy into.  Then you can replace the n1 variable with `input_field`.

Answer (score 8):

More efficiently it can be done as :
For the one who will see the post now should use best practices of javascript.

```
<script>
function sync(textbox)
{
  document.getElementById('n2').value = textbox.value;
}
</script>
<input type="text" name="n1" id="n1" onkeyup="sync(this)">
<input type="text" name="n2" id="n2"/>
```

Comment: Vote up for using best practices!

Answer (score 3):

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function copy()
{
    var n1 = document.getElementById("n1");
    var n2 = document.getElementById("n2");
    n2.value = n1.value;
}
</script>
<label>First</label><input type="text" name="n1" id="n1">
<label>Second</label><input type="text" name="n2" id="n2"/>
<input type="button" value="copy" onClick="copy();" />
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have two textboxes with the same ID. An Id should be unique, so you should prbably change this.

To set the value from one text box to another a simple call to `getElementById()` should suffice:

```
document.getElementById("n1").value=  document.getElementById("n2").value;
```

(assuming, of course you give your secodn text box an id of `n2`)

Tie this up to a button click to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me and it doesn't use JavaScript:

```
<form name="theform" action="something" method="something" />
 <input type="text" name="input1" onkeypress="document.theform.input2.value = this.value" />
 <input type="text" name="input2" />
</form>
```

[I found the code here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?432794-Copying-data-from-one-text-box-to-another-in-html-automatically)

Comment: Technically, that _does_ use Javascript, but you're right in that you don't have to import a separate script in order to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use event "oninput".  This gives a more robust behavior.  It will also trigger the copy function when you copy paste.

Comment: Could you add an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

You can this way also used copy contents of one textbox to another

```js
function populateSecondTextBox() {
        document.getElementById('txtSecond').value = document.getElementById('txtFirst').value;
}
```

```html
<label>Write Here :</label> 
<input type="text" id="txtFirst" onkeyup="populateSecondTextBox();" />
<br>
<label>Will be copied here :</label>
<input type="text" id="txtSecond" />
```